# Error while executing C file containing OPENGL libraries

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, freeglut

I compiled a c file which is using OPENGL libraries using gcc command:

**gcc robot.c -lGL -lglut -lGLU -o robot**
.

It gets compiled successfully, but when I am running the executable generated than I am getting this error:

**error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

On executing locate libGL. The output is :-

> /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGL.so
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGL.so.1
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGL.so.1.0.0
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLESv1_CM.so
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.361.45.18
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLESv2.so
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLESv2.so.2
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.361.45.18
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLX.so
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLX.so.0
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLX_indirect.so.0
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLX_nvidia.so.361.45.18
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLdispatch.so.0
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.10
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.10.0
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.a
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libGLESv1_CM.so.1.1.0
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libGLESv2.so.2
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGL.la
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGL.so
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGL.so.1
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGL.so.1.0.0
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGLESv1_CM.so
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.361.45.18
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGLESv2.so
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGLESv2.so.2
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.361.45.18
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGLX.so
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGLX.so.0
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGLX_indirect.so.0
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGLX_nvidia.so.361.45.18
>   /usr/lib32/nvidia-361/libGLdispatch.so.0
>   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64/libGL.rights
>   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64/libGL.so.1
>   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64/libGL.so.1.6.0
>   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64/libGLU.rights
>   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64/libGLU.so.1
>   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64/libGLU.so.1.3.1

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: How did you compile and link it, what commands did you use or what the Makefile contains?

Comment: Are GL libraries correctly installed? Type `locate libGL` and update your post.

Comment: @purplepsycho updated the post.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine added the compile information.